# Database choice and design for Google Spreadsheets alternative

Tags: database, database-design

We are building a Spreadsheet web app for our clients. They can upload any csv (20 MB+) and then perform operations (listed below) on the data. The data is **highly unstructured**.

Over the last few months we have experimented with a couple of architectures:

1. Initially, we stored the whole grid in 2d array format e.g [ {a: 'b', x:'y'}, {a: 'e'} ] inside of PostGreSQL's JSON data type. But then any cell updated required the whole CSV to be stored in the database. This made the app extremely slow.
2. Next, we moved to MongoDB. This improved the performance but we are still running into performance and scalability issues. Below is our structure.

Our current database design:
PostgreSql Structure:
Table - datasets
id, name, description, etc...

Mongo Structure:
Row 1
_id, column1: value1, column2: value2, _data_set_id = datasets.id
Row 2
_id, column1: value1, column2: value2, _data_set_id = datasets.id
and so on...
Also, we have a mongo index on _data_set_id key to support faster queries of the following types.

```
( db.coll.find({_data_set_id: xyz}) )
```

We are also using hosted mongo from a third party vendor who takes care of sharding, backups, uptime etc. (we don't have devops)

The operations on data are of 2 types:

1. Row operations e.g adding or deleting a row
2. Column Operations e.g adding or deleting a column
   **Most of the operations on the data are column level operations** i.e update only the column in each of the rows.

We have optimized to a point where in mongo works fairly fine with datasets having less than 10k rows. But, beyond that, we are not able to scale. We currently have ~25GB of data in Mongo and within next few weeks we will hit 50GB.
Our current product is a prototype and now, we are reconsidering our database architecture in order to scale better.

The most critical requirements for our database are:

1. Fast Read-Writes.
2. Column querying and updates.
3. Updating single cell (i.e row x, column y) value.

So,

1. Is Mongo the right database for this use case ?
2. If yes, what else (other than indexing, sharding) can we do to scale Mongo ?

P.S
We do realise we can achieve only 2 of [CAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) and also gone through [Cassandra vs Mongodb vs Couchdb vs Redis](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis)
We are also evaluating Couchdb (Master-master replication, MVCC etc but no qynamic querying), Cassandra ([querying on unstructured data is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806170/cassandra-and-unstructured-data)) and HBase(ColumnStore) as alternatives.

Comment: *"Over the last few months we have experimented with multiple architectures"* Did you experiment with more than the two you mentioned?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'- nope. just these 2

Comment: Does your spreadsheet support formulas and cell references? If not, do you plan to?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' - yes

Comment: Spreadsheets don't usually use either a SQL database or a NoSQL database on the back end. You might want to look at the source code for some of the open source spreadsheets before you go any further.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' But, we are only providing a web interface for spreadsheet functions. No stand-alone desktop apps. 
Also, we realize that no sql or nosql database is apt for this use case. But, we are just weighing in all options depending on other's experience.

Comment: Weighing all options? You tried *one* SQL database structure, and *one* NoSQL database structure. And you dismissed decades of prior research into appropriate data structures for spreadsheets. This kind of approach won't scale.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect your database is not actually sharded. If your paying for sharding, you're probably not getting the benefit.

You can then shard by the index which should save you time as the data will end up being stored on one or two shard servers who can then respond more quickly according to your _data_set_id_.

Try typing:

```
sh.status()
```

This should how well distributed your database is. It will probably be only on one shard.

Have a good read of these bits before setting up your shard. It's very difficult to redo the sharding without rebuilding your entire collection!

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/